# Does Application Insights have the concept of formatted messages using properties?

Tags: azure-application-insights

The Windows Event Log has the concept of messages with variables pointing to metadata properties. I am wondering if Application Insights can do the same thing. I couldn't find anything on the internet. For example:

```
const string _loginMessage = "{user} logged in at {time}";
...
telemetryClient.TrackTrace(
    _loginMessage,
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["user"] = user.Name,
        ["time"] = DateTime.UtcNow
    });
```

When rendered and looking at the logs in Application Insights, it would show the full message.

I understand I could wrap TrackTrace and do this myself, but I don't want to if this comes for free.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TrackTrace` method does not support this kind of message-format. You need to write your own logic to implement it.

But for some projects like web app / azure function which has `ILogger` integrated with Application Insights, you can use the `LogInformation` method from `ILogger`. The code like below(it's a web project):

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string _loginMessage = "{user} logged in at {time}";
        string user = "myname222";
        string time = "2021-03-03 vvvvv";

        _logger.LogInformation(
            _loginMessage,user,time);

        return View();
    }
```

After run the project, you can see the formatted message and properties in azure portal:

[image]